# Как открыть второе окно в Javafx

Tags: java, javafx, desktop

Программа состоит из нескольких окно в которых таблицы. При нажатии на MenuItem должна открываться новая таблица (окно) и закрываться старое. Всё время сталкиваюсь с проблемами.

---

Первый скриншот - метод, который открывает новое окно

[image: Вот метод, который открывает новое окно]

---

Второй скриншот - первая ошибка

---

[image: Первая ошибка]
http://rextester.com/TGF28223 - код ControllerMain

---

Текст ошибок

---

```
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2625)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2595)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2435)
at Main.ControllerMain.initialize(ControllerMain.java:125)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2591)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2435)
at Main.Main.start(Main.java:18)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:919)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$11(PlatformImpl.java:449)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(PlatformImpl.java:418)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:417)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:175)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2591)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at TableLiterature.ControllerTableLiterature.initialize(ControllerTableLiterature.java:109)
    ... 37 more

Process finished with exit code 0
```

---

tableLiterature.fxml

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="348.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="TableLiterature.ControllerTableLiterature">
    <children>
      <MenuBar>
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Открыть">
            <items>
              <MenuItem fx:id="btnLiterature" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#openStorages" text="Хранение литературы" />
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Библиотеки" />
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Авторы" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
        </menus>
         <VBox.margin>
            <Insets />
         </VBox.margin>
         <padding>
            <Insets left="20.0" />
         </padding>
      </MenuBar>
        <HBox maxHeight="20.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
            <children>
                <Button fx:id="btnAdd" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#actionButtonPressed" text="Добавить">
                    <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
                    </HBox.margin>
                </Button>
                <Button fx:id="btnEdit" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#actionButtonPressed" text="Изменить">
                    <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
                    </HBox.margin>
                </Button>
                <Button fx:id="btnDelete" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#actionButtonPressed" text="Удалить">
                    <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
                    </HBox.margin>
                </Button>
            </children>
        </HBox>
        <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" VBox.vgrow="SOMETIMES">
            <children>
                <TableView fx:id="tableLitreature" prefHeight="250.0" prefWidth="312.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                    <columns>
                        <TableColumn fx:id="columnName" prefWidth="156.0" text="Название литературы" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="columnAutor" prefWidth="155.0" text="Автор литературы" />
                    </columns>
               <columnResizePolicy>
                  <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
               </columnResizePolicy>
                </TableView>
            </children>
            <VBox.margin>
                <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
            </VBox.margin>
        </AnchorPane>
    </children>
</VBox>
```

Comment: Добавьте код и ошибку текстом

Comment: @Виктор Сделал.

Comment: а что в `tableLiterature.fxml`? (ошибка может быть и в самом файле)

Comment: @МиколаКікець по логике не должно быть, сам проверил только что. Код добавил, может быть я что-то не замечаю.

Comment: Попробуй тянуть ресурсы из главного класа и создавать в "локальную" переменую (Например: `AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getResource("packagename/file.fxml"));` вместо `fxmlLiterature = fxmlLoader2.load();`)

Comment: В твоем случае это VBox root = (VBox) fxmlLoader2.load(Main.class.getResource("TableLiterature/tableLiterature.fxml"));

Comment: @МиколаКікець не-а, та же самая ошибка "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required."

Comment: какая структура файлов в проекте?

Comment: Я прописывал так "../TableLiterature/tab‌​leLiterature.fxml" 
Вот скриншот -   https://pp.userapi.com/c639916/v639916037/72246/YVNptnKFM8U.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка было в том, что fx:id таблицы совпадал с названием класса.